# Chrome is caching amazon's web player, clearing cache isn't working

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, caching

I can't get Amazon's instant player to load.  It continuously shows the spinning blue circle.  If I launch in incognito mode, it loads fine.  This leads my to believe that it's loading a cached version that's corrupted.  I've cleared the cache in Chrome, both through the Chrome UI and by hand, and I still get the same error.  Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what happened.  A couple days ago, it fixed itself.  The laptop screen went dark.  I couldn't turn it off in any way, so I pulled the battery.  When I turned it back on, it was working correctly.  I don't know what caused the fix, because I had already tried pulling the battery.